# embed first only youtube video

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pattern-matching, embed

I am using the following function to show youtube links as videos but the problem is that i dont know to replace more than one videos so how can i limit it to only 1?

php code:

```
function embedYoutube($text)
{

    $pattern = '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/';
    $replacement = '<div style="width:100%;float:left;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;"><iframe width="570" height="315" src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text, 1);
```

The fourth parameter of `preg_replace` is the limit of replacements.